# Signing AOSP with multiple certificates during compilation

Tags: android, android-source

I could successfully download and build the Android OS source code and the OS image is working fine.

The OS was signed with the platform certificate under "build/target/product/security" and i signed my app with same certificate to make it system app.

Further i want to sign the OS with multiple certificates and then app with only one certificates , to verify it still has access to all system services as system app.

Is there any way to sign the OS with multiple certificate?

Comment: what was the shareduserID?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `signature` permissions, your application and the framework should be signed with **the same set** of certificates. Unfortunately, if you sign your app with only one of them, you will receive at runtime Security Exception.